# Capacitance of Nested Spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Imagine that we have two nested spheres and I wish to calculate the capacitance. First of all, I'm able to do the calculation. What I'm confused about is how it is possible for the Electric Field to be nonzero in the region between the inner and outer shell. There's a basic concept that states that the Electric Field is 0 inside a conductor in static equilibrium, but the region between the two shells is certainly inside the outer shell and must be 0.

Comment: There certainly is no such "theorem" (there are no theorems in physics to begin with, that's a mathematical term), unfortunately there is a lot of poor teaching. The electric field (on the inside) due to charges sitting ON the conductor will be zero for the ELECTROSTATIC case. If either condition isn't satisfied, you can make a lightning storm inside a Leyden jar (and high energy physicists do when they are designing accelerator cavities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field inside a conducting material is always zero (assuming of course the material is a perfect conductor). The electric field in a *cavity* surrounded by a conducting material, however, is not necessarily zero when electric charges are present in the cavity.

Comment: I can't understand your answer. The outer shell is a conductor. Hence anywhere inside the outer shell, the electric field must be 0.

Comment: Suppose you hold a big electron in your hands, and we put you in a solid metal box. Would the presence of the metal walls outside eliminate the electric field lines coming from your hands?

Comment: @ Maxim Umansky  Yes. By definition, if we are in static equilibrium what happens is that the arrangement of charge on the metal box must be so that it exactly cancels the field lines coming from my giant electron.

Comment: The field in the conductor will be zero, however the field in the non-conducting parts within the conductor may be different from zero.

Comment: @ Umut E. Usturah: OK, I think I understand.